# Finding a set of scalars such that some conditions hold

Tags: derivatives, inequality

Consider a set of strictly increasing, strictly concave and continuously differentiable functions $f_i:\mathbb{R}_{+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$, where $i \in \{1,...,n \}$ and it holds that $f_i(0) = 0$ $\forall i$. Furthermore, suppose there exist some scalars $\epsilon,x^*, c$, where $c>0$, $x^* > \epsilon > 0$  and they fulfill:
\begin{align}
&\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} f_i'(x^*-\epsilon) = c \\
&\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} f_i'(x^*) < c
\end{align}
I want to find a set of strictly positive scalars $\{a_1,...a_n\}$ such that the following two conditions hold:
\begin{align}
&1) \hspace{2ex} a_i \ge \frac{f_i(x^*) - f_i(x^* - \epsilon)}{\epsilon \cdot c}  \hspace{2ex} \forall i\\
&2) \hspace{2ex} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_i \le \epsilon \cdot c
\end{align}

My approach so far has been to assume that 1.) holds with equality and to show that 2.) is fulfilled with strict inequality:

Given that 1) holds with equality for some $(a^*_1,...a^*_n)$ $\forall i$, we have:
\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a^*_i = \frac{1}{\epsilon \cdot c} \cdot \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} f_i(x^*) - f_i(x^* - \epsilon) \right)
\end{align}
Now, in order for the second condition to hold with strict inequality, it must hold that:
\begin{align}
\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} f_i(x^*) - f_i(x^* - \epsilon)}{\epsilon^2} < c^2
\end{align}
Taking the square root on both sides and using the definition of $c$ we need to show that:
\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} f_i(x^*) - f_i(x^* - \epsilon)}}{\epsilon} < \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} f_i'(x^*-\epsilon)
\end{align}
This is the point where I am stuck. Obviously, when $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} f_i(x^*) - f_i(x^* - \epsilon) \ge 1$ we have that:
\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} f_i(x^*) - f_i(x^* - \epsilon)}}{\epsilon} \le \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} f_i(x^*) - f_i(x^* - \epsilon)}{\epsilon} <\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} f_i'(x^*-\epsilon)
\end{align}
where the second inequality follows from strict concavity of $f_i$. Given my assumptions, is there a way to show that the other case is also fulfilled, i.e. when $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} f_i(x^*) - f_i(x^* - \epsilon) < 1$? Or would you take a total different approach? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a very stupid mistake when deriving the conditions that the scalars must fulfill. It should actually be:
\begin{align}
&1) \hspace{2ex} a_i \ge f_i(x^*) - f_i(x^* - \epsilon)  \hspace{2ex} \forall i\\
&2) \hspace{2ex} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_i \le \epsilon \cdot c
\end{align}
With this conditions, when you set $a_i^* = f_i(x^*) - f_i(x^* - \epsilon) \hspace{1ex} \forall i$  you can easily show that:
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a^*_i = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} f_i(x^*) - f_i(x^* - \epsilon) < \epsilon \cdot\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} f'_i(x^*-\epsilon) = \epsilon \cdot c
\end{align*}
where the strict inequality follows due to strict concavity of $f_i \hspace{1ex} \forall i$.

If anybody gave it some thought, sorry for wasting your time :(.